# Make bootstrap alerts apear and stackable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I want to get a bootstrap alert to apear ontop of the page and disapear after a few seconds. I already did this part but now how can I spawn a alert message and if a second one comes that they stack ontop of each other and if one disapears, all other will move to the Right spot.

Is there an easy solution for this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#successMessage").addClass('slide-down', 200).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
})
```

```css
.slide-down {
  top: 55px !important;
}

.alertNotify {
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: gray; width: 100%; height: 50px;">.
</div>
<label id="successMessage" class="alert alert-success alertNotify" type="button">Test Message</label>
```

Code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks5jnzeg/)

Comment: You can look the toast at Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack your alerts. You can make it using z-index.
the more the z-index it will appear on top.
Example. you can create another class

```
.alertMessage {
  position:fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

which has more z-index than your previous alert.
After that add it to your another alert.

```
<label id="alertMessage" class="alert alertMessage" type="button">Another Message</label>
```